# Track changes inside the collection of complex objects

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, listbox, propertychanged

I have a collection of objects "SourceItemCollection" used to populate the ListBox with checkboxes. Each item of the collection consists of two fields, Item and IsChecked (I've created a small class for this combined items). I would like to track all changes when user selects or deselects something from the collection (not when the button is pressed or something else, but "on-sight"). For this I would like to use another collection "SelectedItems" which will consist only of Items, without IsChecked property (I create and would like to use this collection outside the abovementioned small class of the source collection's items).

The tricky thing is that "SourceItemCollection" doesn't change itself, it always stays the same, changes only the IsChecked property of each item. I do get a notification each time I tick or untick something, but I get it inside the small class of my combined items and I can't access my SelectedItems collection from there.

Comment: You should be able to make the SelectedItems available as a static variable somewhere via a delegate to avoid cross-thread issues.

Comment: I would still use same collection, and query it for selected items in moment I need ( a simple LINQ query). Unless you have huge number of items inside `ListBox`, or should query them very fast, don't see a reason maintaining second collection: you need to worry about correct synchronization of those. No point, imo.

Comment: Mr. B, can you please give an example? My SelectedItems collection is not empty at the beginning, I get the data for it from the database). Then I set "ticks" in my SourceItemCollection by using SelectedItems one.